# Why is Google Geofencing not working in my android app?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geofencing, android-geofence

Ive added all the necessary code from the `google` documentation for implementing `Geofencing` in android. Although I can more or less understand what is going on, im trying to make the process as minimal as possible. Ideally, the user would pick a location and a `geofence` gets set around it. Once user enters the area, it should trigger an action. For now I am just trying to hard-code a location and get that working then take it from there. With that being said the button stuff is probably not necessary or the array-list of specified events.

My question is what is the bare minimum code I need to implement this process and what is the best way to go about it? This is my first android app so go easy on the heckling.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Kick off the request to build GoogleApiClient.
        buildGoogleApiClient();

        mGeofencePendingIntent = null;
        // Get the value of mGeofencesAdded from SharedPreferences. Set to false as a default.
        mGeofencesAdded = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(Constants.GEOFENCES_ADDED_KEY, false);

        // Get the geofences used. Geofence data is hard coded in this sample.
        populateGeofenceList();
        getGeofencePendingIntent();
        getGeofencingRequest();

        addGeofencesButtonHandler(this);

        //Get the UI widgets.
        mAddGeofencesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_geofences_button);
        mRemoveGeofencesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.remove_geofences_button);

        mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME,
        MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000); // Update location every second

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    double lng = location.getLongitude();

        myLat = lat;
        myLng = lng;
        mapCenter = new LatLng(myLat, myLng);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mapCenter));
}

/**
 * Builds a GoogleApiClient. Uses the {@code #addApi} method to request the LocationServices API.
 */
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

private void setUpMap() {

    // Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // set map type
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    // Get the name of the best provider
    String networkProvider = locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
    String gpsProvider = locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

    // Get Best Current Location
    myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(networkProvider);

        // Get latitude of the current location
        double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

        // Get longitude of the current location
        double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

        // Create a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        // Show the current location in Google Map
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));

        //Add Marker For event
        Intent myIntent = getIntent();
        String desc = myIntent.getStringExtra("desc");
        String addr = myIntent.getStringExtra("addr");
        venueLat = myIntent.getDoubleExtra("lat", 0.0);
        venueLng = myIntent.getDoubleExtra("lon", 0.0);

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(venueLat, venueLng)).title(desc).snippet(addr));
    }

}

/*
*
*
*
*
* Geofence Stuff
*
*
*
*
 */


private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    // Reuse the PendingIntent if we already have it.
    if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
    // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when
    // calling addGeofences() and removeGeofences().
    return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.
            FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    return builder.build();
}


/**
 * This sample hard codes geofence data. A real app might dynamically create geofences based on
 * the users location.
 */
public void populateGeofenceList() {
    for (Map.Entry<String, LatLng> entry : Constants.BAY_AREA_LANDMARKS.entrySet()) {

        mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
                // geofence.
                .setRequestId(entry.getKey())

                        // Set the circular region of this geofence.
                .setCircularRegion(
                        entry.getValue().latitude,
                        entry.getValue().longitude,
                        Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
                )

                        // Set the expiration duration of the geofence. This geofence gets automatically
                        // removed after this period of time.
                .setExpirationDuration(Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)

                        // Set the transition types of interest. Alerts are only generated for these
                        // transition. We track entry and exit transitions in this sample.
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                        Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)

                        // Create the geofence.
                .build());
    }
}




public void addGeofencesButtonHandler(View view) {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_connected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    try {
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                // The GeofenceRequest object.
                getGeofencingRequest(),
                // A pending intent that that is reused when calling removeGeofences(). This
                // pending intent is used to generate an intent when a matched geofence
                // transition is observed.
                getGeofencePendingIntent()
        ).setResultCallback((ResultCallback<Status>) this); // Result processed in onResult().
    } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
        // Catch exception generated if the app does not use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
        // logSecurityException(securityException);
    }
}



/**
 * Runs when the result of calling addGeofences() and removeGeofences() becomes available.
 * Either method can complete successfully or with an error.
 *
 * Since this activity implements the {@link ResultCallback} interface, we are required to
 * define this method.
 *
 * @param status The Status returned through a PendingIntent when addGeofences() or
 *               removeGeofences() get called.
 */
public void onResult(Status status) {
    if (status.isSuccess()) {
        // Update state and save in shared preferences.
        mGeofencesAdded = !mGeofencesAdded;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(Constants.GEOFENCES_ADDED_KEY, mGeofencesAdded);
        editor.commit();

        // Update the UI. Adding geofences enables the Remove Geofences button, and removing
        // geofences enables the Add Geofences button.
        setButtonsEnabledState();

        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                getString(mGeofencesAdded ? R.string.geofences_added :
                        R.string.geofences_removed),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show();
    } else {
        // Get the status code for the error and log it using a user-friendly message.
        String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                status.getStatusCode());
        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
    }
}


/**
 * Ensures that only one button is enabled at any time. The Add Geofences button is enabled
 * if the user hasnt yet added geofences. The Remove Geofences button is enabled if the
 * user has added geofences.
 */
private void setButtonsEnabledState() {
    if (mGeofencesAdded) {
        mAddGeofencesButton.setEnabled(false);
        mRemoveGeofencesButton.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        mAddGeofencesButton.setEnabled(true);
        mRemoveGeofencesButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
}


}




/*
* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/



public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {
protected static final String TAG = "geofence-transitions-service";


/**
 * This constructor is required, and calls the super IntentService(String)
 * constructor with the name for a worker thread.
 */
public GeofenceTransitionsIntentService() {
    // Use the TAG to name the worker thread.
    super(TAG);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

/**
 * Handles incoming intents.
 * @param intent sent by Location Services. This Intent is provided to Location
 *               Services (inside a PendingIntent) when addGeofences() is called.
 */
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
        String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
        return;
    }

    // Get the transition type.
    int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

    // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
    if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
            geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

        // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger multiple geofences.
        List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

        // Get the transition details as a String.
        String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
                this,
                geofenceTransition,
                triggeringGeofences
        );

        // Send notification and log the transition details.
        sendNotification(geofenceTransitionDetails);
       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), geofenceTransitionDetails, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
    } else {
        // Log the error.
        Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type, geofenceTransition));
    }
}

/**
 * Gets transition details and returns them as a formatted string.
 *
 * @param context               The app context.
 * @param geofenceTransition    The ID of the geofence transition.
 * @param triggeringGeofences   The geofence(s) triggered.
 * @return                      The transition details formatted as String.
 */
private String getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
        Context context,
        int geofenceTransition,
        List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {

    String geofenceTransitionString = getTransitionString(geofenceTransition);

    // Get the Ids of each geofence that was triggered.
    ArrayList triggeringGeofencesIdsList = new ArrayList();
    for (Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences) {
        triggeringGeofencesIdsList.add(geofence.getRequestId());
    }
    String triggeringGeofencesIdsString = TextUtils.join(", ",  triggeringGeofencesIdsList);

    return geofenceTransitionString + ": " + triggeringGeofencesIdsString;
}

/**
 * Posts a notification in the notification bar when a transition is detected.
 * If the user clicks the notification, control goes to the MainActivity.
 */
private void sendNotification(String notificationDetails) {
    // Create an explicit content Intent that starts the main Activity.
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);

    // Construct a task stack.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

    // Add the main Activity to the task stack as the parent.
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MapsActivity.class);

    // Push the content Intent onto the stack.
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

    // Get a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack.
    PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Get a notification builder thats compatible with platform versions >= 4
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    // Define the notification settings.
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            // In a real app, you may want to use a library like Volley
            // to decode the Bitmap.
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setColor(Color.RED)
            .setContentTitle(notificationDetails)
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_text))
            .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);

    // Dismiss notification once the user touches it.
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);

    // Get an instance of the Notification manager
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Issue the notification
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
}

/**
 * Maps geofence transition types to their human-readable equivalents.
 *
 * @param transitionType    A transition type constant defined in Geofence
 * @return                  A String indicating the type of transition
 */
private String getTransitionString(int transitionType) {
    switch (transitionType) {
        case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
            return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_entered);
        case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
            return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_exited);
        default:
            return getString(R.string.unknown_geofence_transition);
    }
}
}

/*
* --------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/


public class Constants {
private Constants() {
}

public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence";

public static final String SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME = PACKAGE_NAME + ".SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME";

public static final String GEOFENCES_ADDED_KEY = PACKAGE_NAME + ".GEOFENCES_ADDED_KEY";

/**
 * Used to set an expiration time for a geofence. After this amount of time Location Services
 * stops tracking the geofence.
 */
public static final long GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_HOURS = 12;

/**
 * For this sample, geofences expire after twelve hours.
 */
public static final long GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS =
        GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_HOURS * 60 * 60 * 1000;
public static final float GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS = 1609; // 1 mile, 1.6 km

/**
 * Map for storing information about airports in the San Francisco bay area.
 */
public static final HashMap<String, LatLng> BAY_AREA_LANDMARKS = new HashMap<String, LatLng>();
static {

    BAY_AREA_LANDMARKS.put("Home", new LatLng(29.382798, -98.529470));


    BAY_AREA_LANDMARKS.put("Other Home", new LatLng(29.472491,-98.571244));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are few suggestions regarding your code:

- Try to make it more modular. Separate out the code in different files according to the functionality you are expecting them to support (eg, maps code can be separated from location etc).
- Make sure your app has the latest version of Google Play Services and making use of the FusedLocationApi.
- Make sure the geofence radius is altelast 100 meters. Else the enter exit code wont be triggered.
- Add the necessary permissions in the manifest files such as ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, BroadCastreceiver (if you are using) etc.

Please refer to the following [tutorial](http://paulusworld.com/technical/android-geofences) for code implementation.